# Изменение значения в элемента в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код, в этом коде, происходит разложение текста в массив, после чего идет проверка текста с изменением его согласно параметрам.
столкнулся с проблемой что при работе с функцией current(array) - не получается присвоить новое значение. В последнем блоке, подскажите что я делаю не так и как это работает?

```
  if(end($array) == 'UOII'){
      if(prev($array) == 'UOOG'){
          current($array)='UOOOG'; //не происходит присваивание и выдает ошибку

      }else{echo '---';

      }
  }


  print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Функция `current()` просто возвращает значение элемента массива, на
>   который указывает его внутренний указатель.

В отличии от функций `end()` и `prev()` которые сначала устанавливают указатель в массиве на нужный элемент, а затем возвращают значение.

Это тоже самое что пытаться одной строке присвоить другую строку, будет ошибка:

```
'string' = 'UOOOG';
```

В вашем случае можно вообще обойтись без указателей:

```
$count = count($array);
if ($array[$count - 1] == 'UOII') {
  if ($array[$count - 2] == 'UOOG') {
    $array[$count - 2] = 'UOOOG';
  } else {
...
```

Либо если вы хотите использовать указатели, задействуйте функцию `key()` которая возвращает ключ массива на котором сейчас установлен указатель:

```
...
if(prev($array) == 'UOOG') {
    $array[key($array)] = 'UOOOG';
} else {
...
```

Comment: Спасибо! вот как раз не смог нагуглить функцию key()! Спасибо! с count() тоже выходит правильно! но key() позволит ещё в дальнейшем изменять значения если буду использовать prev()